# Filter based on foreign key

Tags: django, django-orm

So i was working on this problem for many days already and can't make it work. Basically I have three models

```
class Year(models.Model):
    year = models.CharField()


class Book(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name = "Library Name",
        max_length = 255
    )

    author = models.ForeignKey(
        Author,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    year = models.ForeignKey(
        Year,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name = "Author's Name",
        max_length = 255
    )

    num = models.CharField(
        max_length = 255,
        default=0
    )
```

For example, If I pass 2018 i want retrieve all the Authors who published book in 2018. 
I tried different queries like `Year.objects.filter(year=2018).filter()`

and don't know how to filter the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter on the content of a related model, by using double underscores (`'__'`), so you can filter on the `year` attribute of the `year` relation of a `Book` of that `Author`:

```
Author.objects.filter(book__year__year='2018').distinct()
```

The `.distinct()` is useful, since otherwise `Author`s who published multiple books in 2018, will occur *multiple* times in the queryset.

That being said, constructing a `Year` object here, seems rather strange, and making it a `CharField` is even more strange (since sorting by `year` will result in sorting *lexicographically). The `num` field in the `Author` model, probably should be an [**`IntegerField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.IntegerField) as well.

A better modeling might be:

```
class Book(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name = "Library Name",
        max_length = 255
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        Author,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    year = models.IntegerField()

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name = "Author's Name",
        max_length = 255
    )
    num = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

In that case we  can query for `Author`s who published a book in 2018 with:

```
Author.objects.filter(book__year=2018).distinct()
```

It is however still unclear what `num` is doing here. If it holds the number of books, then using an `.annotate(..)` might be a better option, since it avoids data duplication.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I can see that year is a **CharField**, so you must use quotes to make the query, and you must use a lookup (`year__year`) to query for a field in a related model.

```
authors = Book.objects.filter(year__year='2018').values('author').distinct()
```